# ACR39U ICC_Timeout issue

Tags: android, smartcard, reader

We use ACR39U smart card reader to access ISO7816 compliant smart cards. Recently we noticed a problem with the card reader. The card reader works well when working with CCID and TPDU on Windows. Yet on Mac OS X and Android device, when we change the card inside the smart card reader, the device does not recognize the card and returns ICC_Timeout response (41h FEh) when ICCPowerOn is sent. When we disconnect the smart card reader and connect it back, the card is read without any problem.

Our primary concern is resolving this issue on Android device. We tried first sending ICCPowerOff and then ICCPowerOn. Even we tried releasing usbDeviceInterface, closing UsbDeviceConnection and reconnecting to the UsbDevice. Yet, we could not solve the issue.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: My first assumption was, that this is a deactivation/switch-off field problem of a contactless card, but according to [manufacturer](https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/302/acr39u-smart-card-reader/) this is a contact-based only reader. Are all of the tried cards from the same manufacturer/type? If you don't insert any card after connecting the reader, do you also get  timeout error? Also a missing reset might be the problem, this is neither automatically done just by doing power-off/power-on, nor by USB disconnect/connect, you need a CardConnect for that.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. We contacted with the card reader company. We used their latest SDK, it worked like a charm. The issue was that we were not listening to bulk-IN messages. Thanks again for your reply.